# Print in flask doesn't work

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import operator, itertools
from collections import OrderedDict
app = Flask(__name__)
L1a = [8, 9, 14, 13, 12]
L2a = [9, 12, 14, 10, 8]
L3a = [26]
L1b = [27, 32, 26]
L2b = [30, 27, 32, 28, 31]
L3b = [31, 30, 26]
OM = [9, 10]
comb = []
@app.route('/')
def html():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/evaluate', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def evaluate():
    LR = float(request.form['LR'])
    impL = float(request.form['impL'])
    ou = float(request.form['ou'])
    od = float(request.form['od'])
    c1 = [(reduce(operator.mul, p), p) for p in itertools.product(L1b, L2b, L3b)]
    c2 = [(reduce(operator.mul, p), p) for p in itertools.product(OM, L1a, L2a)]
    RPL = [(((p[0][0]) / p[1][0]) * LR, p[0][1], p[1][1])  for p in itertools.product(c1, c2)]
    for i in RPL:
        for j in i:
            if i[0] > (impL + (impL * od)) or i[0] < (impL + (impL * -ou)):
                pass
            else:
                comb.append(i)

    unique = []
    [unique.append(i) for i in comb if i not in unique] 
    print 'Avaliable impulses::'
    for i in unique:
        float(i[0])
        n = (100-i[0]/impL*100)
        print 'Result: {0} % '.format(n), str(i[0])
    return "Done"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

and index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="/evaluate" method="post">
  Amount<br>
  <input type="text" name="impL"></input><br>
  Number<br>
  <input type="text" name="LR"></input><br>
  -<br>
  <input type="text" name="ou"></input><br>
  +<br>
  <input type="text" name="od"></input><br>
  1 <input type="radio" name="r1" value="1"><br>
  2 <input type="radio" name="r2" value="1"><br>
  3  <input type="radio" name="r3" value="1"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Calculate"></input>
  <br>

</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to get results(in last for loop) of calculations on webpage. But my `print` statements are not working. Python is not seeing them. In console i can see results without problems. I tried with saving results  to file

```
(file = open("newfile.txt", "w")
file.close()
```

but it wasnt working. If it is not possible to show results with `print` how can i do it in the other way?

Comment: Printing writes to your console (`sys.stdout`) and not to the response, no. Printing *works fine*, but does not do what you expect it to do it appears. Did you want to [stream the response](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/) perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes I want to stream the response but i do not know how to use it in this script

Comment: Use `yield` instead of `print`.

Comment: You may use jinja2 and pass the data from backend to frontend

Answer (score 1):

According to @MartinPeters comment you have to [stream the output](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/). All the output which should be streamed you have to generate via `yield`.

```
@app.route('/evaluate', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def evaluate():
    def generate():
        ...
        yield "Done\n"
    return Response(stream_with_context(generate()), mimetype='text/plain')
```

`stream_with_context` you need for reading form data inside an inner function.

I may will be better if you built up a structure e.g. list and pass it to a template via `render_template`. So you could return a more fancy result.

Comment: 'print 'Result: {0} % '.format(n), str(i[0])' here i am getting error all the time

Comment: Just use a format string like this `yield "Result: %s %% %s" % (n, i[0])`. Your line `float(i[0])` don't cast `i[0]` to float. You have to do `i[0] = float(i[0])` if it's really necessary. You have to look into your code again. It's all a little mixed up.